# Docker container on EC2 frontend doesn't connect to backend

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-ec2, create-react-app

I have deployed a single docker container with a backend and a frontend on it. For various reasons, it is much easier for me to do it this way.

The docker container works fine locally and the FE and BE interact. However, once it's deployed to the EC2 device, only the FE is accessible and it can't connect to the BE.

The FE is a react-app running on port 3000. The BE is a node/express backend with a nodemon server running on port 5000. I know nodemon should be in a dev environment, but if I got it running locally on a docker container there's no reason it shouldn't work on the EC2 device, right?

I have security groups configured correctly for both ports, and I've checked that the container is running on those ports. Which it is.

I feel a bit out of my depth here and, aside from the entire application, is there anything I can provide here that would better help identify what is at issue here?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.17.0

WORKDIR /client
COPY ./client/package.json ./client/package.json
RUN npm i
COPY ./client ./client

WORKDIR /server
COPY ./server/package.json ./server/package.json
RUN npm i
COPY ./server ./server

EXPOSE 3000 5000

WORKDIR /client
CMD ["npm", "run", "remote-start"]
```

The remote start script launches the servers of client and server in tandem. As said, this works fine locally.

I also have configured in the client's package.json the following:

`"proxy": "http://<IP-Address>:5000"`

That works fine for the local docker container when it's `localhost:5000`

Comment: Nodemon is okay to use in prod, it won't hurt anything, but it's also unnecessary if you're running in Docker, have at least two containers, and are using any sort of orchestration system (compose, K8s, etc., anything that will restart failed containers). Are you able to curl http://localhost:5000 and :3000 when SSHd into the EC2 instance?

Comment: Curl works for 3000 but not for 5000

Comment: `curl http://localhost:3000` and `curl http://localhost:5000` should show you some response. You can use the flag `-I` as in `curl http://localhost:5000 -I` to see more info. If you get any response at all, that's a good sign. If this works, then the problem is probably with your networking setup in AWS. If your security groups are good and you have a public IP assigned, the next thing to check would be your ACL.

Comment: Do you have 5000 exposed in your Dockerfile? Can post that code (redacted if needed)?

Comment: hmm, I looked at this a bit more and poked at it. Now if I curl <IP address>:5000 on the EC2 device, it times out. If I curl localhost:5000 I get a result. I have the frontend connecting to <IPAddress>:5000 - I was assuming if I have it as localhost, then it would point to my machine here. Should I change it to localhost:5000 in the code and it'll then direct to the EC2's port 5000?

Comment: No. Localhost refers to the machine making the request; when you're on your machine, that's your machine, and when you're using Curl on the EC2 instance, that's the EC2 instance. Are your security groups for sure configured correctly? Easy way to debug: change them to allow `0.0.0.0/0` for all HTTP and HTTPS traffic, test, and if that works, you know it's your SGs. If that doesn't do it, then it could be a firewall on the instance, or your VPC settings, or your ACL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to Start a React App and Express Backend in One Docker Container on EC2**

OK, I've looked at this. The way to get a react FE and node BE to connect on an EC2 device is the following. This presumes the structure I assume you have from your dockerfile:

```
client
  - package.json (starts a server on p 3000)
  - all client files
server
  - package.json (starts a server on p 5000)
  - all server files
```

1. Use the docker file you've posted above
2. In the react-app client, use your proxy line in the client's package.json with the public IP address of the EC2 device

```
"proxy": "http://<IP-Address>:5000"
```

3. Make sure ports 3000 and 5000 are accessible in your EC2 security groups
4. There's no need to alter anything with where express listens

```
app.listen(5000, () => {
```

5. To start two servers at once, you need a script to support your docker CMD(I assume your `npm run remote start` is like this) that can start them concurrently:

```
    "remote-start": "cd .. && cd server && npm run dev & react-scripts start"
```

Now both the BE and the FE will be running when the container is deployed to your EC2 device and will be accessible via the IP address of the EC2 device.

In testing this, I found the EC2 device might freeze when the container starts. Give it some time and it should work fine.

As mentioned by Zac Anger, you can curl to the ports but use the IP address of the EC2 device to test if its running.

Comment: The structure is a bit different, but I adapted it and it works fine.